# Canvas is not shown when I set render mode to screen space - camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a project containing a few canvases.
The render mode for some of them is set to 'screen space - camera' and for others is set to 'screen space - overlay'.
But the canvases with 'screen space - camera' render mode are not shown in some android devices (for example samsung a10, samsung a50, samsung ace, samsung j3 and j7). But they are OK in unity editor and other devices.  
Also in some devices sometimes the canvas is shown sometimes it is not shown. (for example Huawei Nova3a)
EDIT:
There is a panel in my canvas and its size will be changed in some devices . It causes hiding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is not canvases. 
Do you have anything behind the your canvas? Make sure that canvas is far enough from anything behind it.

Comment: There is not anything else in the scene, just canvases. The screen is blank when 'screen space - overlay' canvases are deactivated.